# How is the THD of a signal calculated? What is the process inside of an automatic distortion meter?

Tags: total-harmonic-distortion, thd

In general, the equation to find the Total Harmonic Distortion (THD) is:

\$THD = \frac{\sqrt{V_{2,rms}^2+V_{3,rms}^2+V_{4,rms}^2+V_{5,rms}^2+...}}{V_{1,rms}} \$

According to attached figure (*A Course in Electrical and Electronic Measurements and Instrumentation* by A.K. Sawhney,) the instrument takes two measurements to calculate the THD:

\$THD = \frac{\sqrt{V_{2,rms}^2+V_{3,rms}^2+V_{4,rms}^2+V_{5,rms}^2+...}}{\sqrt{V_{1,rms}^2+V_{2,rms}^2+V_{3,rms}^2+...}} \$

Why are there two methods? What actually happens here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the distortion (THD) is "low", then we can assume that the denominator of the second definition is "almost" equal to V1rms ...
which is equal to the denominator of the first definition ...

The second definition is easier to measure.